# Login Form to an app including email

Tags: facebook, authentication

Currently we use different steps when an user access to a Facebook app. The first step is the app acceptation, then he's redirected to a form with pre filled data from FB profile (firstname, lastname, email ...). Then, after correction or validation, the user is redirected to the app.

I understood Facebook migrate to new version of API and I don't find if this intermediate form is mandatory or if  validation on app permission is enough.

If someone as the answer with the link that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying a form for the users post app acceptance is not necessarily required for apps that use Facebook signup.  As long as you store the critical data from the user post acceptance/login (user id, email, access token) to verify that the user is in your system then there are no issues.

However, if you wish to allow the user to set overrides over some of the data provided from their user profile or enter any additional data that is not found in their profile data that is required to complete signup then displaying the form would fine.  Typically, Facebook signups are best used without forms.  Users appeal with it is not having to fill out additional forms to join sites and apps.

If the data in the signup form isn't critical to complete your apps signup process, I would suggest moving it to a settings menu to help improve the flow of the signup.